# When do Sharepoint Calculated Columns actually get calculated?

Tags: sharepoint

I'm having some problems with calculated columns in Sharepoint 2007. They don't appear to be working as expected.

So, I decided to try something simple. Basically, I wanted to check a Content Type.

The formula is:
=IF([Content Type]="PictureView","IsPicture","NotPicture")

This column is added to the Default View of the Document Library. I would expect the column to be filled with either "IsPicture" or "NotPicture" (without the quotes).

However, only a few sporadic cells are populated for that calculated column.

Can anyone shed some insight as why this is happening? Why doesn't it populate the entire column?

Thanks!
Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculated columns store their value in the database and are set when the record is updated - they won't be set for records that were already there when the calculated field was added.

Computed fields are calculated on view, but they aren't available through the browser interface.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Hrmm.. any idea why some items are showing a value? These are items that haven't been touched in weeks.

Comment: They may have been modified more recently than you think - being updated doesn't cover only intentional changes. As a quick fix I'd suggest opening the list in datasheet view and copy/pasting a column onto itself so all rows get updated.

Comment: If an expression doesnt evaluate properly it will not return a value properly so that could also be the case. Is it possible that these list items content types are not in that list?